# Как вывести данные из двух таблиц БД в laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

есть 2 таблицы: - users; 
- indom;
Внутри есть 2 одинаковых столбца: settlement; (и в users и в indom)
При регистрации пользователь вводит вручную settlement, и сохраняется в таблице users.
Вопрос: Как сравнить settlement из users и settlement из indom, чтобы потом вывести другие записи уже из таблицы indom из той же строки?
Не судите строго знаю что это вроде просто.(карапуз)

Answer (score 0):

```
$indom = Indom::where('settlement',$user->settlement)->get();
```